# How to prevent visual studio 2017 from adding reference to NugetFallbackFolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I use the feature in visual studio 2017 to suggest `using`s for assemblies in Nuget.

Most of the time, this works perfectly well. But in some occasions, it suggests `dll`s instead of nuget packages.

[image: Vs2017 suggests dlls instead of nuget packages]

How can I force Visual Studio to only suggest nuget packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Tools -> Options -> C# -> Advanced`

Uncheck `Suggest usings for types in reference assemblies`
and check `Suggest usings for types in NuGet packages`

Comment: I add that even if we set these settings, in some circumstances VS just falls back to suggesting `dll`s. One such condition is if VS fails to connect to internet. Then the solution is to restart VS.

Comment: This just disables recommendations for NuGet packages across the board, not only the fallback package folder.

Comment: @user4893106 works ok for the other folks here, also read this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2017CanAutomaticallyRecommendNuGetPackagesForUnknownTypes.aspx